# Using PyTorch DataLoader makes me have the same losses, loops without any progress

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, torch, dataloader

So my issue is that when not using DataLoader, just creating 1000 epochs and doing the learning, the results are ok, and the losses drop to ~0.2. However, when trying to use DataLoader, the output is:

```
|batch|index|loss|
8 0 0.6232748031616211
..
8 23 0.6030591726303101
9 0 0.5626393556594849
9 1 0.6434788703918457
..
9 20 0.6232720017433167
```

I think it means that it doesn't learn on anything new. I do not know how to fix it, though. Doesn't matter if the no. epochs is 10 or 100. Loss is always ~0.6. Here is a code fragment without the model:

```
xy = np.loadtxt('diabetes.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
x_data = (torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 0:-1]))
y_data = (torch.from_numpy(xy[:, [-1]]))


class DiabetesDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):
        xy = np.loadtxt('diabetes.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
        self.len = (xy.shape[0])
        self.x_data = (torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 0:-1]))
        self.y_data = (torch.from_numpy(xy[:, [-1]]))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len


dataset = DiabetesDataset()
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                          batch_size=32,
                          shuffle=True,
                          num_workers=0)


model = Model()

criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction='mean')
optimizer = torch.optim.Rprop(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(10):
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data

        inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)

        y_pred = model(inputs)

        loss = criterion(y_pred, labels)
        print(epoch, i, float(loss.data))
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

What might be the cause? Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is in `batch_size`, you should set small `batch_size` for dataloader

Comment: "Just doing the learning" - one sample at a time or the whole dataset at a time? And is that the only change in your code?

Comment: Before I had a 2 variables that just took in the entire csv without separating data into batches, just x_data that had the values and the y_data with the result column, with the main code looking like this:`for epoch in range(1000):
    y_pred = model(x_data)

    loss = criterion(y_pred, y_data)...optimizer etc
` A very simple exercise.

Comment: Increase your batch size. The model is not getting enough variation and decent data to alter the weights. Also, do you have an imbalance problem?